# Cómo eliminar contorno de las puntas - Angular Material 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

tengo una consulta con respecto a quitar lo que queda de blanco y solo dejar el contorno redondeado, se ve mejor en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El blanco demás que están en las esquinas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como digo, que solo quede el contorno rojo.

Mi código del componente HTML es el siguiente:

```html
<m-portlet [options]="{headLarge: true}" >
   
    <ng-container mPortletHeadTitle>
        <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
            <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text">
                {{title_page}} Orden de Salida de Materiales | {{this.data.trabajador}}
            </h3>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container mPortletHeadTools>
        <div class="m-f">
            <button type="button" [hidden]="hide_insert" (click)="guardarOrdenMateriales(lesson)" matTooltip="Agregar material" color="bg-yellow" mat-mini-fab>
                <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>
            </button> &nbsp;
            
            <button type="button" (click)="OnNoClick()" matTooltip="Regresar al listado" color="bg-blue" mat-mini-fab>
              <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

<ng-container mPortletBody>    
    <div class="m-form m-portlet__body">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="mat-table__wrapper"> 
                <mat-table class="mat-table__wrapper" [dataSource]="listMateriales" #MatSort="matSort" matSort perfectScrollbar>                    
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Orden">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Pos</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{Materiales.indexOf(lesson) + 1}}</mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>
                    
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Centro">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Centro</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.CentroDisplay}}</mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Almacen">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Almacen</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.AlmacenDisplay}}</mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Codigo">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Codigo</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">
                            <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">

                                <input readonly="true" matInput formControlName="Codigo{{lesson.Pos}}" disabled value="{{lesson.Codigo}}">

                                <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="bg-green" class="btnSearchMaterial"
                                    (click)="searchMaterial(lesson)" mat-button color="bg-blue"
                                    matTooltip="Buscar Materiales">
                                    <fa name="search" inverse='true'></fa>
                                </button>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Descripcion">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Descripcion</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{ lesson.Descripcion }}</mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Unidad">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Unidad</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{ lesson.Unidad }}</mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>
                    
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Stock">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Stock</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{ lesson.Stock | number:'1.1-4' }}</mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Cantidad">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Cantidad</mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">
                            <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
                                <input id="inputCantidad{{lesson.Pos}}" maxlength="12"  type="number" step="any" matInput formControlName="CantidadMaterial{{lesson.Pos}}" value="{{lesson.Cantidad}}" (change)="onChangeCantidadMaterial(lesson)">
                                <mat-error> <strong> Obligatorio </strong> </mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="Acciones">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="head_back">    
                            <button type="button" (click)="addMaterial(0)" [hidden]="general_disable" color="bg-blue" matTooltip="Agregar Operacion" mat-mini-fab>
                                <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </mat-header-cell>
                        
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">
                            <button *ngIf="lesson.Estado" mat-icon-button style="color: #F2242E !important" type="button" data-toggle="modal"
                                (click)="deleteMaterial(lesson,!lesson.Estado)" matTooltip="Eliminar">
                                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
                        <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="5"> Loading data... </mat-footer-cell>
                    </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef="no_dataMateriales">
                        <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="5"> No se encontraron registros. </mat-footer-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedMateriales"></mat-header-row>

                    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedMateriales"></mat-row>
                    <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{'hide': listMateriales!=null}"></mat-footer-row>
                    <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['no_dataMateriales']" [ngClass]="{'hide': !(listMateriales!=null && listMateriales.data.length==0)}"></mat-footer-row>
                </mat-table>
             </div>
        </div>
</div>  
</ng-container>

</m-portlet>
```

> No tengo nada en el .css de mi componente.

Espero puedan apoyarme :D

##### UPDATE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado a inspeccionar el DOM y ver qué elemento es ese?? Porque es mucho más sencillo hacer lo que pides con un [mre] que viendo el código sin poder probar. Una de dos, o nos proporcionas un [mre] en algún sitio como stackblitz que permite levantar proyectos de angular, o inspeccionas tú mismo los elementos de tu web y ves cual es, y lo añades el mismo tipo de borde que tienes en la parte roja (con lo cual, lo estarías "ocultando")

Comment: inspecciona el DOM en tu navegador y muéstranos a detalle qué propiedades abarca el contorno del modal.

Comment: Gracias por responder, acabo de agregar una imagen con las propiedades. He intentado reproducirlo en stackblitz pero me faltan dependencias varias y routing, me es difícil.

Comment: Angular tiene por defecto esas esquinas bordeadas en los modales. Intenta darle propiedades entrando a la clase `.modal-dialog` con css, me avisas si te funcionó.

Comment: He intentado darle propiedades de overflow: hidden, padding: 0px, borders: 0px y demás, pero no logro.

Comment: no sería con `border-radius: 0;`?